# C++ redefinition error for two different function signatures

Tags: c++

I have a type, `morton_id_t`, which is a 64-bit number. I have a second type which is a concatenation of the bits of a [Morton ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) (`morton_id_t`) with several bits that contain information about the level in a tree:

```
typedef uint64_t morton_id_t;
typedef uint64_t morton_id_lvl_t;

#define BITS (sizeof(morton_id_lvl_t) * 8)

// number of bits to store the level
#define LEVEL_BITS 6
#define LEVEL_MASK ((1 << LEVEL_BITS) - 1)

// utility functions to pull the level or morton id out of a morton_id_lvl_t
lvl_t level(morton_id_lvl_t n);
morton_id_t morton_id(morton_id_lvl_t n);

// this just strips off the level bits using the `morton_id` function...
bool isAncestor(morton_id_lvl_t ancestor, morton_id_lvl_t descendent);

// ...and calls this
bool isAncestor(morton_id_t ancestor, morton_id_t descendent);
```

`morton_id_t` is just `typedef`'ed from `uint64_t` even though I only need the 64 - 6 level bits.

The compiler throws an error saying that the second `isAncestor` definition redefines the first, even though the type signatures are different.

**How can I define two different `isAncestor` functions, one of which takes `morton_id_lvl_t`'s and the other takes `morton_id_t`'s?**

Do I need to use classes instead of `typedef`'s?

Comment: Use a strong typedef if you want that behaviour (Boost has one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typedef only introduces a new name for a type, it doesn't create a new type, unfortunately.

You could wrap them in structs to turn them into different types:

```
struct morton_id_t
{
    uint64_t id;
};

struct morton_id_lvl_t
{
    uint64_t id_lvl;
};
```

or possibly (not 100% sure that it's valid):

```
struct morton_id_lvl_t
{
    uint64_t id:58;
    uint64_t level:6;
};
```

This would also provide type safety for your conversion functions.

Answer (score 5):

`morton_id_t` and `morton_id_lvl_t` are the same, so the `isAncestor` signatures are the same too.

A `typedef` does not create a new type, but rather an alias for an existing one.

Comment: that tells me why it's not working, but how do i fix it?

Comment: @aaronstacy Do these functions really need to have the same name?

Comment: of course they don't need to. i'd just prefer them to have the same name because i find it, combined w/ their type signature, communicates their purpose well.